# How to specifically mention in a regular expression to avoid 6 characters?

Tags: angular, regex

So I want a regular expression, which would accept numbers or alpha chars. If it's number should start with 1 & it can 3 to 8 characters but it should not be of length 6. If it's alpha, it can be 3 to 6 chars.

This is what I'm using now. My question is How can I avoid 6 char length if it's numeric?

```
      ("^[1][0-9]{2,7} | [A-Za-z]{3,6})$")
```

Can anybody please suggest me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the numeric part in two sub-parts:

`("^([1]([0-9]{2,4}|[0-9]{6,7}) | [A-Za-z]{3,6})$")`

However, the spacing and the parentheses are off. [Corrected expression](https://regex101.com/r/puOnAM/1/):

`^(1([0-9]{2,4}|[0-9]{6,7})|[A-Za-z]{3,6})$`

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^(?![0-9]{6}$)(?:1[0-9]{2,7}|[a-zA-Z]{3,6})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7pdlCZ/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![0-9]{6}$)` - no 6 digit string allowed
- `(?:1[0-9]{2,7}|[a-zA-Z]{3,6})` - either

  - `1[0-9]{2,7}` - `1` and then two to seven digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[a-zA-Z]{3,6}` - three to six ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string